# How to change rect router website language

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[react router website language change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9WHp.png)

My computer, browser and all website language is English but only react router language is difference. I don't understand this language.

Comment: Pretty funny. SO is for general programming questions, I advise you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router)